# JavaFX accessing controller gives nullpointerexception

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

What i'm trying to achieve is getting a controller instance from the main method, so i can call methods of the controller from another class and update the fxml. Anyways here's my code:

Main class:

```
public class Main extends Application {

Controller controller;
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();

    Parent root = fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    controller = fxmlLoader.getController();

    primaryStage.setTitle("uPick Smart Service");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1600, 600));

    primaryStage.show();

    ConnectionHandling connectionHandling = new ConnectionHandling();
    Thread X = new Thread (connectionHandling);
    X.start();

}

public static void main(String args[]){
    launch(args);

}

public Controller getController(){
    return controller;
}


}
```

My controller class:

```
public class Controller {

public HBox billbox;

public int childnr;


public void createBill() {
    System.out.println("Creating");
    TableView<Item> bill = new TableView<>();

    DropShadow dropShadow = new DropShadow();
    dropShadow.setRadius(5.0);
    dropShadow.setOffsetX(3.0);
    dropShadow.setOffsetY(3.0);
    dropShadow.setColor(Color.color(0.4, 0.5, 0.5));

    VBox fullbill = new VBox();
    fullbill.setPadding(new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1));
    fullbill.getStyleClass().add("fullbill");

    TableColumn<Item, String> nameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Emri");
    nameColumn.setMinWidth(200);
    nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));

    TableColumn<Item, String> quantsColumn = new TableColumn<>("Sasia");
    quantsColumn.setMinWidth(50);
    quantsColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("quants"));

    double tablewidth = nameColumn.getWidth() + quantsColumn.getWidth();

    Label tablenrlabel = new Label("Table 5");
    tablenrlabel.getStyleClass().add("tablenr-label");
    tablenrlabel.setMinWidth(tablewidth);

    Button closebutton = new Button("Mbyll");
    closebutton.setMinWidth(tablewidth);
    closebutton.getStyleClass().add("red-tint");

    bill.setItems(getItem());
    bill.setMinWidth(256);
    bill.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
    bill.getColumns().addAll(nameColumn, quantsColumn);

    fullbill.setEffect(dropShadow);
    fullbill.getChildren().addAll(tablenrlabel, bill, closebutton);

    billbox.getChildren().addAll(fullbill);

    childnr += 1;

    //Loops over every button in every vbox and gives it a seperate listener (the index of the button is hardcoded so it can cause problems if you add more items)
    for (int i = 0; i < childnr; i++) {
        VBox box = (VBox) billbox.getChildren().get(i);
        Button btn = (Button) box.getChildren().get(2); //if sudden issues change this
        btn.setId(Integer.valueOf(i).toString());
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                int index = billbox.getChildren().indexOf(btn.getParent());
                billbox.getChildren().remove(index);
                childnr -= 1;
                System.out.println(btn.getId());
            }
        });
    }
    System.out.println("done");
}

}
```

And the class trying to call controller method:

```
public class TakeOrder implements Runnable {
Socket SOCK;
Controller controller;

//OrderIndexes: "Order","Waiter","Payment"

private int NonConnectedDatas = 2;

public TakeOrder(Socket X){
    this.SOCK = X;
}

public void CheckConnection() throws IOException{
    System.out.println("Checking connection");
    if(!SOCK.isConnected()){
        System.out.println("Dissconectiong");
        for(int i = 0; i < ConnectionHandling.ConnectionArray.size(); i++){
            if(ConnectionHandling.ConnectionArray.get(i) == SOCK){
                ConnectionHandling.ConnectionArray.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void run(){
    try{
        try{
            CheckConnection();


            ObjectInputStream ob = new ObjectInputStream(SOCK.getInputStream());

            String[] structuredArray = (String[])ob.readObject();

            String tablenr = structuredArray[0];
            String index = structuredArray[1];

            ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> quants = new ArrayList<>();

            int a = 0;
            int b = 0;
            switch (index) {
                case "Order":
                    for (int i = NonConnectedDatas; i < structuredArray.length; i++) {
                        if (i % 2 == 0) {
                            names.add(a, structuredArray[i]);
                            System.out.println(names.get(a));
                            a++;
                        } else {
                            quants.add(b, structuredArray[i]);
                            System.out.println(quants.get(b));
                            b++;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }

            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                }
            });
        }finally{
            SOCK.close();
        }
    }catch(Exception X){
        System.out.print(X);
    }
}



}
```

And here's my error message:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at sample.TakeOrder$1.run(TakeOrder.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The ConnectionHandling class:

```
public class ConnectionHandling implements Runnable{

public static ArrayList<Socket> ConnectionArray = new ArrayList<Socket>();


public void run(){
    System.out.println("Starting");
    try{
        final int PORT = 60123;
        ServerSocket SERVER = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        System.out.println("Waiting for clients");
        while(true){
            Socket SOCK = SERVER.accept();
            ConnectionArray.add(SOCK);

            TakeOrder ORDER = new TakeOrder(SOCK);
            Thread X = new Thread(ORDER);
            X.setDaemon(true);
            X.start();
        }
    }catch(Exception x){
        System.out.print(x);
    }

}
```

Comment: What does this return? `controller = fxmlLoader.getController();` Does it not set controller to null?

Comment: Yes, it does return null

Comment: Where are you instantiating `TakeOrder` and executing its `run()` method (or passing it to a `Thread`)?

Comment: I took out that part of the code for simplicity's sake, but basically I'm accepting a socket connection, and when that socket connects I start a new thread that creates an object in my fxml with the contents that get send over the socket.

Comment: Yeah, OK, but *where are you doing that*? In the controller? Or where?

Comment: I'm instantiating it from the ConnectionHandler class which gets instantiated in the main method. See updated question.

Comment: Updated answer accordingly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you are using the **`static`**  [`FXMLLoader.load(URL)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load-java.net.URL-) method. Because it's `static`, the controller property of the `FXMLLoader` instance you created isn't initialized by calling this `load` method. So `controller` in `Main` will be `null`.

Instead, set the location and use the instance method [`load()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load--):

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));

    Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
    controller = fxmlLoader.getController();

    primaryStage.setTitle("uPick Smart Service");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1600, 600));

    primaryStage.show();



}
```

This doesn't entirely solve your problem, though. When you launch the application, JavaFX will create an instance of `Main` and call `start()` on that instance. With the changes above, the `controller` field of *that instance* will be properly initialized.

However, in `TakeOrder.run()` you create another instance of `Main`:

```
Main main = new Main();
```

The `controller` field for that instance won't be initialized (and even if you do initialize it, it's not the same as the instance you want). So you really need to arrange for `TakeOrder` to access the *controller instance created in the start method*.

Here is the most straightforward fix to your code to make that work:

```
public class ConnectionHandling implements Runnable{

    private final Controller controller ;

    public ConnectionHandling(Controller controller) {
        this.controller = controller ;
    }

    // ...

    public void run(){

        // existing code ...

        TakeOrder ORDER = new TakeOrder(SOCK, connection);

        // ...
    }
}
```

and

```
public class TakeOrder implements Runnable {

    Socket SOCK;
    Controller controller;

    //OrderIndexes: "Order","Waiter","Payment"

    private int NonConnectedDatas = 2;

    public TakeOrder(Socket X, Controller controller){
        this.SOCK = X;
        this.controller = controller ;
    }

    // ...

    public void run() {

        // ...

        Platform.runLater(controller::createBill);

        // ...
    }

}
```

and finally

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();

        Parent root = fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        Controller controller = fxmlLoader.getController();

        primaryStage.setTitle("uPick Smart Service");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1600, 600));

        primaryStage.show();

        ConnectionHandling connectionHandling = new ConnectionHandling(controller);
        Thread X = new Thread (connectionHandling);
        X.start();

    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        launch(args);

    }

    public Controller getController(){
        return controller;
    }


}
```

In general for applications such as this, you probably want to think about using a MVC or MVP approach (i.e. you need a *model* class, which would hold the services, such as your `ConnectionHandler`).

You might also be interested in [this article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javafxinteg-2062777.html) on integrating services in JavaFX.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. More googling for me it seems :D

Comment: @user6535530 If you explain in your question where you are creating the `TakeOrder` instance, it might be pretty simple to answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you manually instantiate your `Application` which in this case is the `Main` class, then the `start()` function won't be called. Try launching your application with

`Application.launch`

instead of

`Main main = new Main()`

Also, the `launch` method does not return until the application has exited. Thus, you may want to somewhat reorder your call to getController()

There's also another way to manage the instance of your controller and that is to use `setController(Object controller)` from your FXMLLoader.

---

Docs:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String...-

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#setController-java.lang.Object-